# how to transfer files from windows file share to ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a folder full of files in a windows file share on the network. I need to grab that folder every day and put it on a few linux (ubuntu) computers. I was wondering what is the easiest way to do that automatically (script-wise).

Comment: For scripted transfer, I'd use FTP or SFTP. After all, "**F**ile **T**ransfer **P**rotocol" is the name of the utility.

Comment: I'd write a shell script that mounts the share, `rsync` the files somewhere local, and then rsync them to the remote linux systems via ssh/sftp.

Comment: I myself *might* do the FTP/SFTP option.. but not as my first choice.  I would keep these files shared on the windows side and use smbclient/cron task to PULL them from the windows machine to the linux clients via bash script.  I think this a mostly the same idea that @FrankThomas is eluding to. `mount` with  `rsync` would be a nice touch :)  Linux accessing windows share is SUPER easy (pull).  FTP is *mostly* easy (push).  Getting permissions right with samba as a server (push) sucks (but is also VERY possible).

Comment: If you *do* use samba client to `mount` and `rsync`, but sure to `umount` after.  All hell breaks loose (on the linux side) if the windows share goes down while `mount`ed.  You WILL NOT like it ;)